# Irritable Bowel Syndrome Constipation, FODMAPS and consumption of fiber

Tags: digestion, irritable-bowel-syndrome

If an individual has symptoms of irritable bowel syndrome constipation (IBS-C) and is following the [low FODMAPS guidance on the foods](http://www.ibsdiets.org/fodmap-diet/fodmap-food-list/) to consume , there appears to be a significant amount of information on consuming low fiber. Noted a few sources.

1. [IBS Diet](http://www.ibshelponline.com/ibs-diet.html)
2. [Primal Parent](http://theprimalparent.com/2011/08/31/understandingpoop-constipation-ibs-digestive-disorders/)
3. [Fiber Menance](https://www.gutsense.org/fibermenace/about_fm.html)

There are also sources that list the amount of fiber that should be consumed over a day

1. [Super Kids Nutrition](http://www.superkidsnutrition.com/mt_howmuchfiber/)
2. [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/diet/guide/fiber-how-much-do-you-need)
3. [Prebiotin](https://www.prebiotin.com/low-fodmap-diet-for-ibs-work/)

The sources contradict the intake of fiber and would like to understand impact either on kids & adults in regards to IBS-C and FODMAPS.